# How to show all 3 urls are null in following table in postgresql/sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to show records where url is null and typeurl of type1 & type2 also null.
Output should be productname : Oil

```
ProductName     Url    Type     TypeUrl
Shampoo         null   Type1    null
Shampoo         null   Type2    www.domain.com
Conditioner     null   Type1    null
Conditioner     null   Type2    www.domain.com
Oil             null   Type1    null
Oil             null   Type2    null
```

postgresql query I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a simple aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT ProductName
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ProductName
HAVING COUNT(Url) = 0 AND
       COUNT(TypeUrl) FILTER (WHERE Type IN ('Type1', 'Type2')) = 0;
```

For versions of Postgres which do not support `FILTER`, use this version:

```sql
SELECT ProductName
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ProductName
HAVING COUNT(Url) = 0 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Type IN ('Type1', 'Type2') THEN TypeUrl END) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for ur help.I am using Postgresql where I am getting syntax error near where.

Comment: @Pinky Check the updated answer for another version which should work.